# Add Algolia faceting setting from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I am using Algolia with Rails 4 and everything is working. I am curious about adding a faceting setting from Rails, not from my dashboard.

Is that possible? If it is, how can I implement this in my Rails project?

I only saw `attributesForFaceting` from rails but it doesn't add in Algolia `facets` setting.

Did I use the `attributesForFaceting` method wrong? If so, how can I use it as the attribute of `refinementList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At indexing time, so in your rails app, `attributesForFaceting` is indeed the parameter you want to change.
Quoting [the docs here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rails#faceting):

> ```
> class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
>   include AlgoliaSearch
>
>   algoliasearch do
>     # [...]
>
>     # specify the list of attributes available for faceting
>     attributesForFaceting [:company, :zip_code]
>   end
> end
> ```

You should check in *Your Algolia dashboard > Your Index > Display tab* that this setting is correctly set.

The [`facets` parameter](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest#param-facets) is used to specify the list of facets you want to retrieve at query time.

> List of object attributes that you want to use for faceting. [...]
>   Only attributes that have been added in `attributesForFaceting` index setting can be used in this parameter.
>   You can also use `*` to perform faceting on all attributes specified in `attributesForFaceting`.

However, since you're using `instantsearch.js` in your front-end, you should set `attributeName` on the faceting widgets.
In this example with a [`refinementList`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#refinementlist), we want to retrieve the `brand` facets:

> ```
> search.addWidget(
>   instantsearch.widgets.refinementList({
>     container: '#brands',
>     attributeName: 'brand'
>   })
> );
> ```

The widgets in `instantsearch.js` will then use this `attributeName` parameter to set the `facets` parameter that Algolia's API expect.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation. All I have to do is reindex my model. Thanks for answering. :D